# Populate Drop Down List using jquery from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a textbox whose id is other and I want to populate this textbox value into drop down list
 This is javascript I am using to populate... but this is not working.. Any suggestion will be appreciated...!! I want to do like this:- 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/dynamic-combobox-listbox-dropdown-in-javascript.html

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript"> 
function addCombo() {
    var textb = $('#other').attr('id');
    var combo = $('#category').attr('id');
    alert(combo);

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = $('#other').val();
    alert(option.text);
    option.value = $('#other').val();
    try {
        combo.add(option, null); //Standard 
    }catch(error) {
        combo.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
}
</SCRIPT>
```

---

This is the code of drop down list

```
<td>Category</td>
                    <td><select class="size" id="category" name="category" width="30px">
                    <option width="30px" value="" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                    <option value="food">Food</option>
                        <option value="rent">Rent</option>
                        <option value="gas">Gas</option>
                        <option value="enter">Entertainment</option>
                        <option value="grocery">Grocery</option>
                        <option value="general">General</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option></select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Other</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="other" name="other"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" data-role="button" value="Add" onclick="addCombo()"></td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its because

```
var textb = $('#other').attr('id');
var combo = $('#category').attr('id');
```

Aren't you assigning id's of these elements to variables, instead of elements?
I mean... is textb really a input element after this code executes, or is it just a string "other"?

Try this:

```
var textb = $('#other');
var combo = $('#category');
```

Edit:

```
function addCombo() {
    var textb = document.getElementById("other");
    var combo = document.getElementById("category");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = textb.value;
    option.value = textb.value;
    try {
        combo.add(option, null); //Standard 
    }catch(error) {
        combo.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
}
```

Comment: I tried using the above code.. But textbox value wasn't added in the drop down list.. Any other help??

Comment: Before I do some debuggin.. why you just don't use their code? You aren't changing it anyway. You just changed way to find the elements (pure js instead of jQuery. I posted wrking code for your case.

Comment: Now I am more confused.. So I have made two different links.. Currently I am working on this link (http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing1.html) and on this I want the textbox value to get into drop down list and in this it is not working properly as you can try by inserting.... But on this link(http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing.html) the same code is working fine.. Value is getting inserted into drop down list.. what is the problem??? bcoz of some jquery plugins??

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery:

```
function addCombo() {
    var optName = $("#other").attr("value");
    $('#category').append("<option value='"+ optName + "'>" + optName  + "</option>");
    $("#other").attr("value", "");
}
```

Comment: @crocodilewings I tried using the above code.. But textbox value wasn't added in the drop down list.. Any suggestions??

Comment: Are you using a debugger, like Firebug?  What, if anything, is being appended to the select element?

Comment: @dampe Now I am more confused.. So I have made two different links.. Currently I am working on this link (http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing1.html) and on this I want the textbox value to get into drop down list and in this it is not working properly as you can try by inserting.... But on this link(http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing.html) the same code is working fine.. Value is getting inserted into drop down list.. what is the problem???

Comment: @Raihan Jamal: The first one isn't actually using a <select> element to present the list.  It has a script which builds a list-like display out of other elements at page load using the content of the <select> element.  Anything that then gets added to the <select> after the page has loaded won't appear in the list-like display.

Comment: @crocodilewings I am not using any script for that select element.. Or is there something that I am missing??

Comment: @crocodilewings: Uh, nice catch! I didn't see that ;)

Comment: @dampe @crocodilewings Any suggestions?? I was reading on the internet and I found this:-  
Q24(b). If I include JQuery I'm able to populate a SELECT control and/or a UL control with the categories I have in a database. Without changing anything else, if all I do is include JQuery mobile to stylize my app then the code for populating the SELECT stops working but populating the UL control still works. I get no errors or warnings in the google chrome debugger. 

A. Are you refreshing the SELECT? See refresh Select

Comment: @Raihan Jamal: It's jquery-mobile that's doing it.  It takes the <select> element and makes a prettier mobile-device-style front-end for it.  It just doesn't update the front-end when the <select> is appended.

Comment: @crocodilewings Yes I got to know this when I started working on two links... One is working fine other is not... So what should I do..?

Comment: @Raihan Jamal: [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-add-items-and-refresh-the-select-menu-in-jquery-mobile) explains how to refresh your select.

Comment: Sry, I don't have any experience with jQuery mobile. I guess that you will need to discover that refresh possibility. Or find, what function is called to transfer select to list. And then call this function each time you add new select option. Or you can of course append <li> instead of <option>, but then you will have to somehow handle sending values from the list.

Comment: @dampe Thanks a lot for your help.. @crocodilewings So for refreshing my select.. this is the actualy syntax that I have to do... And it will be in script tag??
//  $("#selectbox").html(optionList).selectmenu('refresh', true);
   $("#category").html(option).selectmenu('refresh', true);

Comment: @Raihan Jamal: I think you'll actually just want $('#category').selectmenu('refresh'); after the code that appends the select box.

Comment: @crocodilewings Thank a lot for your help... But that one is also not working..  I wrote like that:--   ' <SCRIPT language="javascript"> 
function addCombo() {
    var optName = $("#other").val();
 alert(optName);
    $('#category').append("<option value='"+ optName + "'>" + optName  + "</option>");
    $("#other").attr("value", "");
$('#category').selectmenu('refresh');
 }
 
</SCRIPT> '

Comment: Try adding $('#category').selectmenu('refresh', true); as I think this will force a rebuild of the menu.  [This Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835527/jquery-mobile-how-to-re-render-select-box) seems to be the same issue.

Comment: @crocodilewings I think there is something wrong that I am doing.. the above one is also not working for me correctly...!! I am doing like this.. You can check the link(http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing1.html)

'<SCRIPT language="javascript"> 
function addCombo() {
    var optName = $("#other").attr("value");
 alert(optName);
$('#category').append("<option value='"+ optName + "'>" + optName  + "</option>");
    $("#other").attr("value", "");

    $('#category').selectmenu('refresh', true);
 }
 
</SCRIPT>'

Comment: Any other help will be really appreciated as still I am not able to do this thing properly...!!

Comment: All out of clues here.  You could try looking through the documentation for jquery mobile.

Comment: @crocodilewings Anywaz thanks for your help.. really aprreciated your help... I don't know how I am going to do that thing now... :(