# Populate Drop down from Text box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have an asp.net drop down list box and I want to populate it based on the value of the text box via javascript. The value is passed to the stored procedure which I created and the results will be populated in the drop down.

I did my research but I can't seem to find the right solution to this.

Need help please.

 
[UPDATE]
Here's the source code which I initially did:
HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="cboPriceID" AutoPostBack="true" onblur="LoadPrice()"/>
```

And I have a dataTable which is retrieved from the stored procedure. What I currently have is a javascript code which populates the textbox.

```
        function LoadPart_CallBack(response) {
        //if the server-side code threw an exception
        debugger;
        if (response.error != null) {
            //we should probably do better than this
            alert(response.error);

            return;
        }

        var ResponseValue = response.value;


        var al = ResponseValue.split(":");
        var errormsg = al[0];
        var partname = al[1];


        if (errormsg == "") {

            document.getElementById("<%=txtPartName.ClientID%>").value = partname;
          }
        }
```

Need help on how to populate it.

Comment: Have a look at this question **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511273/populate-drop-down-list-using-jquery-from-textbox**

Comment: @Amit: not much actually to add. I just have my dropdown control there. I'm still thinking of how to cascade it based from the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="data" name="data"/>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addData()"><br/>
<select id="choice">
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addData()
{
    var txt=document.getElementById("data").value;
    if(txt!="")
    {
     var newcontent = document.createElement('option');
     newcontent.innerHTML = txt;
     document.getElementById("choice").appendChild(newcontent);
     document.getElementById("data").value="";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```