# spring mvc dynamic on change dropdown to other dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

i have two dropdown list.
first drop down:1
    enter code here

```
<form:select path="custName" id="custName">
    <form:option value="walk_in">Walk In</form:option>
    <c:forEach var="led" items="${name}">
        <form:option value="${led.ledName}">${ledger.ledName}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

second dropdwon  :

```
<form:select path="customerName" id="c01">
        <option value="walk_in">Walk In</option>
        <c:forEach var="led" items="${name}">
        <form:option  value="${led}">
        </form:option>
        </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
```

I have the following Spring Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/accreq")
```

with the following mapping

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/creditAccount_name.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String GetName(@RequestParam(value="credit",required=true)String customername, ModelMap model){
            List<Journal> journals=journalDao.getReceiptTypeName(customername);
            System.out.println(customername);
            String ID = journals.get(0).getJournalId().toString();
            System.out.println(ID);
            return ID;//here i am getting the value in console
        }
```

I'm trying to call this method with the following jquery ajax

function getAjaxReceipt(){

```
var custname=$("#custName").val();
if(custname!="walk_in"){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'creditAccount_name.htm',
        data:{credit:custname},
        success:function(data){
            $('#c01').val(data);//this is the feild id of second drop down value should display here...but is show empty...
            alert(data);//here also i am getting the alertbox in jsp
        },
        error:function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState=0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0)
                return;
        },
    });
}
```

The Scenario is i am getting the value of first dropdwon through query and binding it in controller.when i select the value of the first dropdown ,its corresponding value should bind in 2nd drop down.

for that i have used ajax and jquery...i am successfully get the value to the controller and passing the valuing to ajax..But the problem is the value is not binding in the dropdown box.
Can any one tell me what might have gone wrong?

The prblem is after the value is displayed in alert...its not showing in second dropdown.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am seeing in the second drop down like `<form:option  value="${led}"></form:option>`. You are having the value for that drop down but there is not display label set for that, but for the first drop down you have like `<form:option value="${led.ledName}">${ledger.ledrName}</form:option>`. Is that something properly done but you are not displaying it right?

Comment: @viquar is "led" an list of objects of some type. since in the first combo you have accessed like "led.ledName" right, but in the second dropdown you have assigned the object itself to the value, like value="{led}". Should it be assigned the similar way you are doing in the first dropdown. One thing you can do try to view the html and see how it looks before changing the first dropdown. because in ajax you are getting one string value but in the second drop down you assigned the value of dropdown as "led" object.

Comment: ,bro in the second drop down i have given only value=${led} ,even i tried with value=${variableName.led},its not showing the value ...its not binding...y is that so?

Comment: one thing i dont understand is the drop down one and two you are trying to populate the same values. is that by requirement. also is "led" an object, i mean what is the type of that object. is that your own custom object? as i told earlier the drop down is not having a label. can you try doing like this <form:option value="${led.ledName}">${led.ledName}</form:option> and check?

Comment: i have tried like tht also but still its not showing the value in drop down...y am i getting the value i alertbox but not in dropdown....

Comment: only way is to view the html once you render the page, and see what are all the values that is there in the dropdown 2. if there is no values at the load time itself then obviously it may not show up in the ajax call also...

Answer (score 1):

What i understand you can succsesfully getting data from  server .So your url ,mappings and params correcly send.But returned response not reflected in browser .If I i understand correct you need to refresh page(dom tree,or spesific component ) with new data .Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835527/jquery-mobile-how-to-re-render-select-box)

Comment: brother the value is also display in the alert..but not in the DropDrown feild.

Answer (score 0):

Your Current code will not work because its an ajax call. And $ function works only on page load, its means it will bind any variable only on page load. thats why You have to delete your options html code of second dropdown and add java script code for second drop down options as below :

```
myselect = document.getElementById("c01");
```

//second option

```
theOption=document.createElement("OPTION");

theText=document.createTextNode("JavaScript Tutorial II");

theOption.appendChild(theText);
```

//this option has a value, an URL, so we set the value

```
theOption.setAttribute("value","index.html");

myselect.appendChild(theOption);
```